# How Does the Healer Feat Interact with Polymorph?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, healing, polymorph

When you are Polymorphed, say into a T-Rex with 13 hit dice, and are healed by someone using the Healer feat you would recover 1d6+17 hit points. After polymorph has worn off, but prior to completing a short rest, are you able to be healed again by the Healer feat? Would you be considered a different creature for the purposes of determining whether you could be healed by the feat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### No, the target of *polymorph* is the same creature in a different form.

Quoting from the description of *polymorph* in the SRD (emphasis mine):

> This spell transforms **a creature** that you can see within  range into **a new form.**

The target's statistics change to match that of the new form, but that's the extent of the change.

As a tangential, we can also look at all the *additional* issues that might crop up if this answer were different:

- Would the target still be attuned to magic items they were previously attuned to?
- Would all active spells or effects targeting them cease to have an effect?
- Would the target still be obligated to pay off their tab at the local inn?

Answer (score 6):

**No.**

According to the Polymorph spell description...

> This spell transforms a creature that you can see within range into a new form.

Nowhere in the spell description is there an indication that the spell changes a creature into a different creature. Rather, the target stays the same creature but in a new or different form. So, regardless of the current form, if the creature has been healed through the use of the Healer feat then it cannot be healed again through that feat until it has rested.

That is a reading of the rules as they are written. Nevertheless, an argument can be made in support of a DM's ruling that the Healer feat could be used to heal each form distinctly: because 1) the new form's hit points are assumed and the old form's hit points are set aside and because 2) the new form is capable of resting using its own hit dice, then thematically each form maintains its own health or wellness independently. However, keep in mind that such a ruling could allow players to exploit the Polymorph/Healer loophole to get additional healing in violation of the usual rest cycle at the expense of arcane spellcasting resources, in addition to violating the rules as written.